# How to use random.sample() within a for-loop to generate multiple, *non-identical* sample lists?

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I would like to know how to use the python `random.sample()` function within a `for`-loop to generate multiple sample lists that are **not identical**.

For example, right now I have:

```
for i in range(3):
    sample = random.sample(range(10), k=2)
```

This will generate 3 sample lists containing two numbers each, but I would like to make sure none of those sample lists are identical. (It is okay if there are repeating values, i.e., `(2,1)`, `(3,2)`, `(3,7)` would be okay, but `(2,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(5,4)` would not.)

Comment: Beside the point, but `(2,1)` and `(1,2)` aren't identical. You might want to treat them as [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s, in which case they would be identical.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. This is a good first question! :)

Comment: How many numbers do you need?  In this particular case, you could generate a list from 0 through 9, then use `random.shuffle` to shuffle the items, and pull them off one by one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
import random
import math

# create set to store samples
a = set()
# number of distinct elements in the population
m = 10
# sample size
k = 2
# number of samples
n = 3

# this protects against an infinite loop (see Safety Note)
if n > math.comb(m, k):
    print(
        f"Error: {math.comb(m, k)} is the number of {k}-combinations "
        f"from a set of {m} distinct elements."
        )
    exit()

# the meat
while len(a) < n:
    a.add(tuple(sorted(random.sample(range(m), k = k))))

print(a)
```

With a `set` you are guaranteed to get a collection with no duplicate elements. In a set, you would be allowed to have `(1, 2)` and `(2, 1)` inside, which is why `sorted` is applied. So if `[1, 2]` is drawn, `sorted([1, 2])` returns `[1, 2]`. And if `[2, 1]` is subsequently drawn, `sorted([2, 1])` returns `[1, 2]`, which won't be added to the set because `(1, 2)` is already in the set. We use `tuple` because objects in a `set` have to be hashable and `list` objects are not.

***I hope this helps. Any questions, please let me know.***

---

**Safety Note**

---

To avoid an infinite loop when you change 3 to some large number, you need to know the maximum number of possible samples of the type that you desire.

The relevant mathematical concept for this is a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

- Suppose your first argument of `random.sample()` is `range(m)` where
  `m` is some arbitrary positive integer. Note that this means that the
  sample will be drawn from a population of `m` distinct members
  without replacement.
- Suppose that you wish to have `n` samples of length `k` in total.

The number of possible `k`-combinations from the set of `m` distinct elements is

> m! / (k! * (m - k)!)

You can get this value via

```
from math import comb
num_comb = comb(m, k)
```

`comb(m, k)` gives the number of different ways to choose `k` elements from `m` elements without repetition and without order, which is exactly what we want.

So in the example above, `m = 10`, `k = 2`, `n = 3`.

With these `m` and `k`, the number of possible `k`-combinations from the set of `m` distinct elements is 45.

You need to ensure that `n` is less than 45 if you want to use those specific `m` and `k` and avoid an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you **specifically** need to "use `random.sample()` within a for-loop", then you could keep track of `sample`s that you've seen, and check that new ones haven't been seen yet.

```
import random

seen = set()
for i in range(3):
    while True:
        sample = random.sample(range(10), k=2)
        print(f'TESTING: {sample = }')  # For demo
        fr = frozenset(sample)
        if fr not in seen:
            seen.add(fr)
            break
    print(sample)
```

Example output:

```
TESTING: sample = [0, 7]
[0, 7]
TESTING: sample = [0, 7]
TESTING: sample = [1, 5]
[1, 5]
TESTING: sample = [7, 0]
TESTING: sample = [3, 5]
[3, 5]
```

Here I made `seen` a `set` to allow fast lookups, and I converted `sample` to a `frozenset` so that order doesn't matter in comparisons. It has to be *frozen* because a `set` can't contain another `set`.

**However**, this could be very slow with different inputs, especially a larger range of `i` or smaller range to draw samples from. In theory, its runtime is infinite, but in practice, `random`'s number generator is finite.

---

#### Alternatives

There are other ways to do the same thing that could be much more performant. For example, you could take a big random sample, then [chunk](/q/312443/4518341) it into the desired size:

```
n = 3
k = 2
upper = 10
sample = random.sample(range(upper), k=k*n)
for chunk in chunks(sample, k):
    print(chunk)
```

Example output:

```
[6, 5]
[3, 0]
[1, 8]
```

With this approach, you'll never get any duplicate numbers like `[[2,1], [3,2], [3,7]]` because the sample contains all unique numbers.

<sub>*This approach was inspired by [Sven Marnach's answer on "Non-repetitive random number in numpy"](/a/8505754/4518341), which I coincidentally just read today.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to make a nested list of certain list items without repetition from original list, you can try below code.

```
    import random

    mylist = list(range(50))

    def randomlist(mylist,k): 
      length = lambda : len(mylist)
      newlist = []
      while length() >= k:
        newlist.append([mylist.pop(random.randint(0, length() - 1)) for I in range(k)])
      newlist.append(mylist)
      return newlist

    randomlist(mylist,6)


[[2, 20, 36, 46, 14, 30],
 [4, 12, 13, 3, 28, 5],
 [45, 37, 18, 9, 34, 24],
 [31, 48, 11, 6, 19, 17],
 [40, 38, 0, 7, 22, 42],
 [23, 25, 47, 41, 16, 39],
 [8, 33, 10, 43, 15, 26],
 [1, 49, 35, 44, 27, 21],
 [29, 32]]
```